# Error connecting to a AWS IoT Core websocket endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, mqtt, aws-iot

I'm trying to do a minimal example of connecting and publishing to a topic using MQTT + Websocket + AWS IoT + paho.mqtt.golang and am running into issues. I'm roughly following this tutorial https://oliverdunk.com/2022/06/04/aws-iot-core Here's my code and output:

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    MQTT "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang"
)

func main() {
    MQTT.ERROR = log.New(os.Stdout, "[ERROR] ", 0)
    MQTT.CRITICAL = log.New(os.Stdout, "[CRIT] ", 0)
    MQTT.WARN = log.New(os.Stdout, "[WARN]  ", 0)
    MQTT.DEBUG = log.New(os.Stdout, "[DEBUG] ", 0)

    topic := flag.String("topic", "", "The topic name to/from which to publish/subscribe")
    broker := flag.String("broker", "tcp://iot.eclipse.org:1883", "The broker URI. ex: tcp://10.10.1.1:1883")
    user := flag.String("user", "", "The User (optional)")
    id := flag.String("id", "testgoid", "The ClientID (optional)")
    payload := flag.String("message", "", "The message text to publish (default empty)")
    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Printf("Sample Info:\n")
    fmt.Printf("\tbroker:    %s\n", *broker)
    fmt.Printf("\tclientid:  %s\n", *id)
    fmt.Printf("\tuser:      %s\n", *user)
    fmt.Printf("\ttopic:     %s\n", *topic)
    fmt.Printf("\tmessage:   %s\n", *payload)

    // Load client certificates
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("./iot-certificate.pem.crt", "./iot-private.pem.key")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Load CA certificates
    caCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./AmazonRootCA1.pem")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)

    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
        RootCAs:      caCertPool,
        ClientAuth:   tls.NoClientCert,
        ClientCAs:    nil,
        MinVersion:   tls.VersionTLS13,
        // ALPN and SNI extensions specified by https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/custom-auth.html#custom-auth-websockets
        NextProtos: []string{"mqtt"},
        ServerName: "{ID}.iot.{REGION}.amazonaws.com",
    }

    opts := MQTT.NewClientOptions()
    opts.AddBroker(*broker)
    opts.SetClientID(*id).SetTLSConfig(tlsConfig)
    opts.SetUsername(*user)
    opts.SetMaxReconnectInterval(10 * time.Second)

    client := MQTT.NewClient(opts)
    if token := client.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        panic(token.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println("Sample Publisher Started")
    fmt.Println("---- doing publish ----")
    token := client.Publish(*topic, byte(0), false, *payload)
    token.Wait()
    client.Disconnect(250)
    fmt.Println("Sample Publisher Disconnected")
}
```

and here's my output:

```
Sample Info:
        broker:    wss://{ID}.iot.{REGION}.amazonaws.com/mqtt
        clientid:  test
        user:      ?x-amz-customauthorizer-name=IoTAuthorizer
        topic:     test
        message:   hello, world
[DEBUG] [client]   Connect()
[DEBUG] [store]    memorystore initialized
[DEBUG] [client]   about to write new connect msg
[ERROR] [client]   websocket: protocol "mqtt" was given but is not supported;sharing tls.Config with net/http Transport can cause this error: unexpected EOF
[WARN]  [client]   failed to connect to broker, trying next
[ERROR] [client]   Failed to connect to a broker
[DEBUG] [store]    memorystore closed
panic: network Error : websocket: protocol "mqtt" was given but is not supported;sharing tls.Config with net/http Transport can cause this error: unexpected EOF
```

I'm using a custom authorizer called `IoTAuthorizer` that just returns a default policy and does no authentication. The TLS information was generated in the AWS console under "AWS IoT Core > Security > Certificates". The certificate is marked as "Active" and has a policy attached. Token validation is off for the authorizer.

Comment: This error is from [`gorilla/websocket`](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/main/client.go#L385). Please try changing `tls.Config` to specify `NextProtos: nil,` (or `NextProtos: []string{"http/1.1"},`).

Comment: Note that [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html#protocol-port-mapping) indicates that client certs are not supported when using websockets. If you are trying to use MQTT over TLS on port 443 (which seems to be supported on AWS) then use an `mqtts://...` URL).

Comment: @Brits How would I use a custom authorizer and websockets? The table you linked says that's possible. I tried the same code, used the default RootCAs, and removed the NextProtos field and got the error `connect got error websocket: close 1005 (no status)`

Comment: Sorry - have not tried that (but according to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/custom-auth.html#custom-auth-mqtt) you can use the MQTT username/password or HTTP query params/headers). Quick search on `1005` indicates this may well be an auth issue.